# Vim: remap an accent

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

To use the Spanish layout one has to remap an accent like the one over o: `ö` to `:` in Normal Mode. How can I do this in my `.vimrc`? I have to handle the accent only, not a character; I have no idea how to approach this task.

Comment: Do you mean insert mode? You dont want to lose `:` in Normal mode.

Comment: Sure I don't want to loose colon in Normal Mode. I want to keep it, because in Spanish layout it is stolen by an umlaut. I want to catch half a character (umlaut) and map it back to colon. All in Normal Mode, yes.

Comment: Take a look at `help langremap`

Comment: Already taken :) . I don't need a character. I need just an umlaut. _Half_ a character, that is.

Comment: Depends on how youre entering the umlaut (or tréma) then. If it’s at the OS level, you might be stuck (and need to fix it at that level)

Comment: No way for that to be at the OS level. It's just a keystroke, exactly the same as colon  with the English layout.

Comment: Im confused: on my keyboard, o and : are separate chars. To enter ö i type Alt-: o (i use a macbook). So, i could change that at the OS level. In vim i type Ctrl-k o : to use the digraph feature. How do you enter ö? Are you saying you have a single key that is just the :-part of the umlaut?

Comment: Umlauted ö is entered this way (in terms of the English layout): (1) colon, which means umlaut; (2) `o`, which means `o`. How am I supposed to catch the umlaut and nothing else?

Comment: Try my answer below

Comment: It really looks like you're using a keyboard layout with **dead keys** in your OS. That means vim won't really see the umlaut/colon until you press another key, and if the next key takes an umlaut (e.g. a vowel) you'll get the modified symbol instead. You might want to consider using a keyboard layout without dead keys by default (using a modifier to turn a let into a dead key is an option, using AltGr, which is the Alt key on the right side of the keyboard, is a common choice.) The way to configure that will depend on the OS you're using, search on Google you'll find a guide.

Answer (score 1):

Open vim. Enter insert mode (`i`), then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (`<C-V>` in vim notation) and hit your umlaut key. That should give you the key that vim sees, if any. You can map that key by

```
nnoremap <umlaut> :
```

Where `<umlaut>` you enter via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> as above.

If that method doesn’t produce a distinct key, but instead waits at another level (the terminal emulator, keyboard, window manager, OS, &c.) then you’ll need to fix it at that level somehow.

Comment: We are almost there :) . After <C-V> umlaut shows all right. On Esc it disappears.

Comment: When you hit the umlaut normally does it show the umlaut while waiting for the next key?

Comment: Yes, it does. Probably, it still does not count as a complete character.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov my guess as well. Somebody will need to show you how to map that key at a higher level to do the right thing. Do you have a colon somewhere else on the keyboard?